# DotNetOpenAuth with Yahoo,AOL results in Timeout or NameResolutionFailure

Tags: oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth 3.5.0.10357 and when attempting to authorize using Yahoo as the provider (https://me.yahoo.com) **often times** a ProtocolException is thrown at OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier). If another attempt is made immediately after the first attempt, the workflow behaves as expected. I've added a XRDS document as per [this](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/why-yahoo-says-your-openid-site.html) blog post and when the Yahoo provider responds it seems to detect the file as it no longer displays  that verification message. All other providers, with the exception of AOL which has the same issues, work properly at all times. I've enabled logging and there seem to be two different causes, one is a timeout another is a NameResolutionFailure, both from WebException.

Here is the log from the instance resulting in NameResolutionFailure:

> HTTP GET https://me.yahoo.com/ WebException NameResolutionFailure from
>   https://me.yahoo.com/, no response available. Error while performing
>   discovery on: "https://me.yahoo.com/":
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while
>   sending a direct message or getting the response. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'me.yahoo.com'     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.UntrustedWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Request(IDirectWebRequestHandler
>   requestHandler, Uri uri, Boolean requireSsl, String[] acceptTypes)
>   at DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Discover(IDirectWebRequestHandler
>   requestHandler, UriIdentifier uri, Boolean requireSsl)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.UriDiscoveryService.Discover(Identifier
>   identifier, IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean&
>   abortDiscoveryChain)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.Discover(Identifier
>   identifier)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.AuthenticationRequest.Create(Identifier
>   userSuppliedIdentifier, OpenIdRelyingParty relyingParty, Realm realm,
>   Uri returnToUrl, Boolean createNewAssociationsAsNeeded) Performing
>   discovery on user-supplied identifier: https://me.yahoo.com/ Filtering
>   and sorting of endpoints did not affect the list.

The following is the log from a timeout:

> HTTP GET https://me.yahoo.com/ WebException Timeout from
>   https://me.yahoo.com/, no response available. Error while performing
>   discovery on: "https://me.yahoo.com/":
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while
>   sending a direct message or getting the response. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out     at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.UntrustedWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Request(IDirectWebRequestHandler
>   requestHandler, Uri uri, Boolean requireSsl, String[] acceptTypes)
>   at DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Discover(IDirectWebRequestHandler
>   requestHandler, UriIdentifier uri, Boolean requireSsl)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.UriDiscoveryService.Discover(Identifier
>   identifier, IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean&
>   abortDiscoveryChain)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.Discover(Identifier
>   identifier)     at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.AuthenticationRequest.Create(Identifier
>   userSuppliedIdentifier, OpenIdRelyingParty relyingParty, Realm realm,
>   Uri returnToUrl, Boolean createNewAssociationsAsNeeded) Performing
>   discovery on user-supplied identifier: https://me.yahoo.com/ Filtering
>   and sorting of endpoints did not affect the list.

I'm using the default configuration settings. I'm guessing I cat get around the timeout error by increasing the timeout setting, however I'm not sure how to go about the name resolution error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception this doesn't look like a DotNetOpenAuth-specific problem to me.  It looks like your DNS server is slow or you have a bad connection to it.  I'd look into that problem.  And yes, increasing the timeout will help you in a pinch.

Comment: Is there a way to cache the results of a discovery?